# Modifying a table to accept different data elements

Tags: ms-access

I have created a workflow system where users can see their work in a queue, mark it complete, and create an outgoing correspondence letter. In the Access DB, essentially they are going into each record which has an "Incomplete" indicator and marking items as "Complete" from the queue table.  After doing this, an insert is triggered, which inserts customer data based on that record being marked into a letter table.  A pdf is then batched/printed based on the inserted data from this letter table.

The beginning scope of the project was a single transaction type with essentially limited data fields Such as: Name, Address, State, Zip.  I am finding now that I am being asked to expand the transaction types in the queue.  Different letters however, require different fields and not all fields are readily available for each letter (Some letters need and have an account issued date, others do not, etc).

My question pertains to the methodology of "expanding" the fields available for letter insert.  I need to add more fields for the new transaction types in the letter table.  But these fields are transaction specific, so for example, I may have some kind of audit letter that does not use account premiums, but now I have another transaction that uses only account premiums.  All my letters in the table will share that field if I create it, regardless of whether they actually use it or not. So if that is the case, how should I deal with the nulls? I am wondering if I should still create the field aptly named (such as "AccountPremium", or should i use generic names like "extraField1" and just match it to the point in the letter??

Comment: I would keep specific field names if I were you.  When you go back 2 years later and have to work on this, you're going to hate yourself for using generic field names.  Maybe make one query for each letter type, and only pull in the fields you need into that query?

Comment: That is kind of what I am thinking, just let the nulls populate.  I guess in the table descriptions, I can define which transaction types use that field..